# Difference between "they thought that the general would lead them to victory" and "they thought that the general would have led them to victory"?

Tags: differences

1. They thought that the general would lead them to victory.

*vs.*

2. They thought that the general would have led them to victory.

Is there a difference between the two sentences above? Is one grammatically incorrect?

There is no particular context. I am more interested in learning the difference between the two (if any) and how the subtlety in wording affects the overall meaning.

Comment: I think both are grammatical. The meaning difference is heavily dependent on context. You need to provide at least some context in order for the question to be answered.

Comment: (1) is about anticipating a future victory, (2) about looking back at one that didn't happen.

Comment: @Kate: But of course you can also use (1) when talking about a victory that didn't happen. It's a question of perspective — are you describing what the people were feeling then, or are you looking back at it with hindsight?

Comment: @PeterShor - Of course. _Anticipating_ doesn't necessarily imply that the hoped-for event definitely happens.

Comment: Why are you not including your own diagnosis, so far as it got?